# Code in C# for a console application project that consumes a dll from another project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, console-application, exe, dllimport

I am using visual studio for this. I have test project which generates a dll and runs the different tests everytime I build the project. Now i want to write a console application which generates an exe that consumes the dll generated above. Can I do it using dllImport? If yes, please tell me how?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to:

1. Add the test project in the same solution then,
   [image]
2. add reference to project from your console application.
   [image]

Now when you build the solution the library project will built first and its .dll will automatically be included in the bin directory of you console project. The advantage of doing this instead of referencing just the built .dll is you can modify and debug the source of your library project, e.g. step into it's methods.

However you can just do the second step and instead of adding a reference to your project browse to to the built .dll and add that as a reference.

Comment: So basically if I add the dll as a reference everytime I try to build the solution will it take the newly generated dll from the test project?

Also, the console application need not have any code in it is it?

Comment: no, follow what I said, it will take the dll every time. The console application will use the dll - what is the point of having a console application if it has not have any code? you will of course need a Main method.

Comment: I want to make an exe which will run all the tests from my other project using PSExec on remote machines.

Comment: Exactly!! that is what i was looking for initially

Comment: @user3152409 Provided whether you 'copy local' as false. Anyway dll's must be copied to the exe's folder. Otherwise the exe can't be executed. Apart from that when you compile a dll from some other project and refer the dll in another project ,then you may face file lock on dll. Which will lead you to recompile, sometimes restart the projects.

Comment: How do I copy the dll to the exe folder? I want to know what code should be written in the console app to make the exe work.

Comment: I already said: "....dll will automatically be included in the bin directory ". How the heck I would I know how to code your solution to your problem you haven't told me about? Anyway that is another question.

Answer (score 0):

You can either

1. Add the test project in the same solution then,
2. Add reference to project from your console application.

OR

1. Include a folder named Tests into your console app.
2. Add the test dll generated in it.
3. Add reference to project from your console application.

Answer (score 0):

You can [add reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx) :

In Solution Explorer, right-click the project node and click Add Reference.

In the Add Reference dialog box, select the tab indicating the type of component you want to reference.

Select the components you want to reference, and then click OK.

[image]